# IE Automation VBA - Hidden Button

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, button, automation

I am trying to automate the login via a website and have come across what I believe is a hidden button.

Using inspect element this all I have to work with.

```
<button onclick="javascript:ga('send', 'event', 'Sign In','click','Sign In');" type="submit">Sign In</button>
```

I have tried using `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByName` Etc but I am unfamiliar with hidden items or how to access them. Is there a way cycle through and the ID tags of hidden items?

The URL is:
https://www.eurocarparts.com/login?

Any assistance would appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a link to the website? This button has no ID or Name attribute by the way.

Comment: it would be easier to be sure if there is an URL to share.

Comment: https://www.eurocarparts.com/login?

Comment: What do you want to do with said button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop all the document buttons until you find the one that has type "Submit" and "Sign In" inside:

```
Set allButtons = YOURIEOBJ.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
Do While i < allButtons.Length
    If allButtons(i).Type = "submit" And allButtons(i).innerText = "Sign In" Then
        allButtons(i).Click
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Sometimes innerText doesn't give you the "Sign In". You can use .Text, or .innerHTML, one of them will give you the "Sign In".

Comment: Thanks Ricardo for the response, .innertext and .innerHTML just go into an eternal loop so not finding anything appropriate, .Text causes a runtime error 438, "Object does not support this property or method. I have now included the URL https://www.eurocarparts.com/login?

Comment: Ignore previous I have now got that working, thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go using CSS Selector

Requires VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library and Internet Controls

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetButton()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium, html As HTMLDocument '<==InternetExplorerMedium rather than InternetExplorer because for some reason I was getting interface unknown without the change

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.eurocarparts.com/login"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Dim button As HTMLButtonElement
    Set button = html.body.querySelector("body > section > section.container.content-section.cookiebar > section.row.account-container > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-6.account-box.first > div > form > button")

End Sub
```

If you put in the immediate window the following:

```
?button.innerhtml
```

You get:

```
Sign In
```

Note: @SIM's excellent abbreviation.

```
.querySelector("button[onclick*='Sign In']").Click
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for having a look. Agree with most.  I used ExplorerMedium because I kept getting interface unknown for just InternetExplorer. Pretty sure my settings are fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: To be fair. You could post your css improvement as an answer and I would upvote it, and rollback my death by lengthy CSS.

Comment: Sure you can. Sorry for that. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't be sorry. I am happy to learn from you! Post and I will rollback. But please do post the better answer!

Comment: Until you post as answer here is SIM's excellent answer .querySelector("button[onclick*='Sign In']").Click